# Search string with spaces

Tags: php, string

My problem is that I can't search with spaces. The search words is included in my url: http://prosjektdatabasen.com/index.php?url=search&query=fish+chips
The results returns nothings. Only when I use one word.. Any suggestions?

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
             <input type="hidden" name="url" value="search" /> 
    <input type="text" name="query" class="text" placeholder="Søk etter prosjekter.." style="height:12px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="" class="search-button" />
</form>
```

```
$query = $_GET['query']; 

$min_length = 2;


if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);


    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT *, account_created FROM users
        WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`motto` LIKE '%".$query."%')ORDER BY account_created DESC") or die(mysql_error());
     $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of $query in PHP? Is it correct?

Comment: What is $query. You have to use $_REQUEST['query'].

Comment: Consider using a fulltext index to search for multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$queries = explode("+", $_GET['query']);
  $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT *, account_created FROM users
    WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$queries[0] ."%') OR (`username` LIKE '%".$queries[1] ."%') OR (`motto` LIKE '%".$queries[0]."%') OR (`motto` LIKE '%".$queries[1]."%') ORDER BY account_created DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Now its possible to use two words but it just returns all users or motto that is in the table users.

Answer (score 0):

This is the URL encoding and decoding problem, space and other special characters will be converted to safe equivalent.

You need to decode url

```
<?php
    $varr = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($url)); 
    $varr = html_entity_decode($url,null,'UTF-8');
?>
```

**Update**

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
echo utf8_decode(urldecode( $query));
```

**Input:**

```
$query = "fish+chips";
```

**Output:**

```
fish chips
```

Comment: what is the problem now ?

Comment: It still returns nothing. Only one word is working. Added the code in the top

Comment: Output is correct. If i do a search on fish+chips it still not find anything from the database. I have a user with name fish and motto chips, returns empty.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are try to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that it can't find the user "fish" if i search "fish chips". People will use the search in different ways. The easiest way is ofc to search fish, but i want a more wider search function.